# trying to add .fadein effect after .addclass

Tags: jquery, background, fadein, addclass

Im trying to make the background fade in when hover an item.
tried to add .fadeIn after .addClass but it wont help.

```
$(function() {
$("#item1").hover(function() {
$('.result').addClass("result_hover");

}, function() {
$('.result').removeClass("result_hover");
});    
});


$(function() {
$("#item2").hover(function() {
$('.result').addClass("result_hover2");

}, function() {
$('.result').removeClass("result_hover2");
});    
});
```

this is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/barzioni/jg21y3du/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css transition for that

```
.result {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.result_hover {
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
.result_hover2 {
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

**fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/vka54mqd/1/**

Comment: I want to give it fading out too.. saw already this option of css

Comment: gave transition to result too that's work fine for me thank you!!

Comment: I've updated the answer, the initial state should be 'ease-out', hover class 'ease-in', that should prevent any unwanted fading.

Comment: works great! thank you!, is there any way to make it with background image? it's not the same way with the transition: http://jsfiddle.net/barzioni/0eqsxzt0/

Comment: It works only when there is some initial background image, which change would be animated: http://jsfiddle.net/e7hLe5cd/

Answer (score 0):

try this . in your case you cant use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, because at the initial stage you are hidden(`fadeOut`) your element.so where to hover. so try it in this way.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.first{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border:1px solid black;
}

.addbackground{
 background-color: orange;
}

</style>

<body>


<div class="first"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
$(".first").mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).addClass("addbackground");
});


$(".first").mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).removeClass("addbackground");
});



</script>

</html>
```

hope this will help to you.